# 交差検証（クロス・バリデーション）を適応して意味のあるアルゴリズムについて

Tags: 機械学習

モデル評価にクロスバリデーションをよく使うのですが、
決定木のようなバリアンスの大きいアルゴリズムについては、クロスバリデーションによる評価が意味のあるものかどうか、いつも疑問を抱いて行っています。

そもそもクロスバリデーションは最適なハイパーパラメータを探索することを目的にしていると思っているのですが、最終的なアウトプットとしてのモデルを評価するには、結局は別の検証データセットを用意しておかなければ評価できないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

あなたが何をどう「評価」したいかに寄ると思います。

学習データのみでよいのであればクロスバリデーションをせず、学習データに適したモデルで終了

学習データで作成したモデルを新規のデータに適用したいのであれば

- クロスバリデーションなしの学習モデル
- クロスバリデーションした学習モデル

を新規のデータで試し、実際の結果と比較しているとよいと思います。
ほとんどの場合で後者が勝つので一般にはクロスバリデーションをする、となっています。